# How to merge options object passed in constructor as properties

Tags: javascript

I want to create a class that takes an `options` object as it's argument in its constructor. Each of the member of option object should become member of the class instance.

```
const __defaults = {
   isDisabled = false,
   caption: undefined
}
class Button {
   constructor(options) {
       this.caption = options.caption || __defaults.caption;
       this.isDisabled = options.isDisabled || __defaults.disabled;
   }
}
```

Is there a better way to handle this like spread operator?

```
this.config = { ...options, ...__defaultOptions };
```

The only problem is I can't assign directly to `this` using spread operator. That would be an invalid assignment.

```
this = { ...options, ...__defaultOptions };
```

I want to create all properties directly inside class and not within a config property in the instance. That way when I initialize my button in following manner...

```
const registerButton = new Button({ isDisabled: true });
```

I can read property just like this:

```
console.log(registerButton.isDisabled);
```

and not like this...

```
console.log(registerButton.config.isDisabled);
```

Former approach is more verbose and readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Object.assign` can assign the merged properties onto the instance.

```
constructor(options) {
  Object.assign(
    this,
    __defaultOptions,
    options
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I am marking this as correct answer since this is the closest to what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```js
class Foo{
  constructor(options)
  {
    Object.assign(this,options);
  }
}

let foo = new Foo({a:1,b:2,c:3});
console.log(foo);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a temp object i.e `obj` and then loop over the object keys and then add property on `this`

```js
const __defaults = {
  isDisabled: false,
  caption: undefined,
};
class Button {
  constructor(options) {
    const obj = { ...options, ...__defaults };
    Object.keys(obj).forEach((k) => (this[k] = obj[k]));
  }
}

const registerButton = new Button({
  isDisabled: true
});
console.log(registerButton);
```